# How can i find $dz$ and $d^2(z)$ from implicit equation?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, partial-derivative, implicit-differentiation

Given the function $F(x+z,y+z)=0$,i need to find $dz$ and $d^2z$....here's my attempt:

$$dF=F'_1d(x+z)+F'_2d(y+z)=0$$
$$F'_1(x'dx+z'dz)+F'_2(y'dy+z'dz)=0$$
$$F'_1(dx+dz)+F'_2(dy+dz)=0$$
$$dz=-\frac{F'_1dx+F'_2dy}{F'_1+F'_2}$$ where $F'_1$ is derivative by first component,and $F'_2$ by second one.How can find $d^2z$ from the last equation?

Answer (score 1):

Using primes for derivatives in multivariable calculus is a bad idea. Consider it outlawed. Using subscripts, as in $F_1$, $F_2$, is a good idea.

But I would do this: let $G(x,y,z)=F(x+z,y+z)$. Find the partials of $z$ in terms of the partials of $G$, which is a standard, though nonenjoyable computation: e.g., 
$$z_x = -G_x/G_z\tag1$$
hence by quotient and chain rules
$$z_{xx} = (-G_x/G_z)_x = -((G_{xx}+G_{xz}z_x)G_z - G_z(G_{zx}+G_{zz}z_x ))/G_z^2$$
where $z_x$ comes from (1). Then plug in the particular form of $G$.